# Cheap batteries for old laptop

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an old laptop with a kaput battery.

I have looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1440/where-to-get-laptop-replacement-parts) with regards to spares, but most of the sites that are linked too from there have batteries which probably cost more than the laptop is worth. I like keeping the laptop around as a spare, but find it fustrating that it has to be plugged in permanantly.

It seems to be that a half good battery would be acceptable for me, for a knock down price. However nothing of the sort seems to exsist.

Is there any way to get cheep batteries in such a case?

*Laptop is a Compaq Presario 900 if that information helps*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is looking out on ebay for laptops that are broken, often they are advertised as for parts / repair.

If you just want to take the battery you may be able to sell it on again after keeping that component for yourself.

Comment: Any broken laptop that is more than 12-18months old is likely to have an equally degraded battery - especially with older nimh cells.

Comment: The asker only needs a degraded battery. Theirs dosn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of them on Ebay and it seems like they cost around 40$. I think it would be hard to get anything cheaper since this is not really a market with a lot of buyers.

[Here is one for 26$, about a third of AtBatts 77$.](http://cgi.ebay.com/COMPAQ-PRESARIO-900-GENUINE-BATTERY-280207-001_W0QQitemZ380141884873QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_0?hash=item588238d5c9&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14&_trkparms=65%3A15%7C66%3A2%7C39%3A1%7C293%3A1%7C294%3A50)

Answer (score 2):

Just so a search on Amazon with the model of your computer.  There's a ton of battery sellers on there and it's where I got a $35 battery for my Dell laptop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few places that will refurbish batteries - they take your existing unit, open it up and replace the nimh/li-ion cells inside.
It's cheaper than replacing the entire battery an easier on older batteries since you can generally find replacement cells that will fit even if nobody makes the battery anymore.